# MifareUltralight.transceive throws a IOException on SDK24

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

I have an App which write SRAM in NTAG using MifareUltralight class in android.

using this snippt of code

```
protected boolean fastWrite(byte[] payload) throws IOException {
    byte[] command = new byte[3];
    command[0] = FAST_WRITE_COMMAND; // 0x3A
    command[1] = NxpTag.SRAM_STARTING_PAGE;// 0xF0
    command[2] = NxpTag.SRAM_LAST_PAGE; //0xFF
    byte[] commandAndPayload = new byte[command.length + payload.length];
    System.arraycopy(command, 0, commandAndPayload, 0, command.length);
    System.arraycopy(payload, 0, commandAndPayload, command.length, payload.length);
    return sendNxpCommand(commandAndPayload)[0] == ACK;
}

private byte[] sendNxpCommand(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    byte[] answer;
    answer = mfu.transceive(bytes);
    if (answer == null) throw new IOException("null");
    return answer;
}
```

everything went smoothly until I test it against new Device "Cyrus CM17" which has android 7(SDK 24) and I get always when I use `transceive(data)` to write anything I get `IOException("Transceive failed")` .

So I changed my code and instead of writing the whole SRAM (64bytes) I tried to write only 4 bytes a once by using this code:

```
private boolean writeSRAM(byte[] byteArray) throws IOException {
    boolean res = true;
    byte[] command = new byte[6];
    command[0] = (byte) 0xA2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        command[1] = (byte) (NxpTag.SRAM_STARTING_PAGE + (byte) i);
        System.arraycopy(byteArray, 4 * i, command, 2, 4);
        res &= (mfu.transceive(command)[0] == ACK);
    }
    return res;
}
```

it returns the same exception on the CYRUS device and it works for modern devices `Samsung M21 (SDK 32)`

So I deceied to take the advantage of `MifareUltralight` and I used `writePage(pageNum, Data)` method

```
private boolean writeSRAMPages(byte[] byteArray) throws IOExcepti
    boolean res = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        mfu.writePage(240 + i, Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArray, 4 * i, 4 * (i + 1))); 
    }
    return res;
}
```

and finally it works for old and new devices. the source code of `writePage(pageNum, Data)` use internally `transceive(cmd, false)` while the `transceive(data)` use `transceive(cmd, true)` and the implementation of `transceive(byte[] data, boolean raw)` is:

```
/** Internal transceive */
byte[] transceive(byte[] data, boolean raw) throws IOException {
    checkConnected();
    try {
        TransceiveResult result = mTag.getTagService().transceive(mTag.getServiceHandle(),
                data, raw);
        if (result == null) {
            throw new IOException("transceive failed");
        } else {
            return result.getResponseOrThrow();
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "NFC service dead", e);
        throw new IOException("NFC service died");
    }
}
```

SO when I use `transceive(cmd, true)` on CYRUS with SDK24  it doesn't work because it can't handle `raw = true`. in debugging this method `transceive(byte[] data, boolean raw)` I forced `raw = false` and It worked.

I could still use `writePage(pageNum, Data)` but the app would run slow as I had to send 16 commands instead of 1 each time I need to read the whole SRAM.

Can anyone explain why some devices on SDK24 can't handle `transceive(data, true)` ?.